# Link to a Google Wave

Tags: google-wave

How can I link to a Google Wave, say e.g. in a website or an email like

> Hey, just have a look to this new <a href="???">Wave</a> I created.

, where ??? is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try first answer from [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/wave/thread?tid=35ef351c978cb203&hl=en) page:

1) Edit any Wave

2) Drag the Wave you want the link for into the Wave you are editing

3) Right click on the hyperlink that is automatically added from Step 2

4) Click on "Copy link address"

5) Paste the link address wherever you need

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with ZhukovRA, but this doesn't seem to work completely.

The problem is that unless you are a participant of a wave, you don't see anything. So linking directly to a wave only makes sense if the wave is public.

The direct link generated looks like this: https://wave.google.com/wave/#restored:wave:googlewave.com!1234567890 - where 1234567890 is the wave's ID, from what I can gather.

There's a Wordpress plugin for embedding waves, which is featured here: http://mashable.com/2009/09/08/google-wave-wordpress-plugin/